# Reading object from Google Cloud Storage always returns null

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I wish to read/write a blob to GCS via GAE. However, I am facing a very weird issue:

I write an object (HashMap) to GCS using:

```
GcsOutputChannel outputChannel =
      gcsService.createOrReplace(fileName, GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance());

  ObjectOutputStream oout =
      new ObjectOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));
  oout.writeObject(content);
  oout.close();
```

Now when I attempt to read the same object, it always returns null!

```
GcsInputChannel readChannel = gcsService.openPrefetchingReadChannel(fileName, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
  ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(readChannel));
  Object obj = oin.readObject();
  System.out.println("obj is " + obj); //this obj is null!!
```

I can also see the Object created using the GCS browser and see the timestamp and that it has some size.
Before reading, I can get the metadata of that object and it returns fine and has the correct length too! Just that "readObject" returns null!
Tried other Object serialization methods but to no avail.

The funny thing is that I am able to write String as byte[] to the bucket and read it back without any issue. So don't think there is any problem related to permission/configuration.

This happens on localhost as well as production.

GAE Java 1.9.17
GCS appengine-gcs-client-0.4.4.jar
google-api-services-storage-v1-rev26-1.19.1.jar

Does anybody know what could be going wrong?

Thanks, Asim

Comment: do you have `outputChannel.waitForOutstandingWrites()` somewhere in your code after you finish writing?

Comment: Hi Igor, no I do not have waitForOutstandingWrites() in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flush your writes to GCS also, by calling `outputChannel.waitForOutstandingWrites()`, like:

```
GcsOutputChannel outputChannel =
  gcsService.createOrReplace(fileName, GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance());

ObjectOutputStream oout =
  new ObjectOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));
oout.writeObject(content);
outputChannel.waitForOutstandingWrites()
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the line waitForOutstandingWrites(), but still no luck.

Comment: are you sure that you aren't writing `null` into this file?

Comment: wow, thanks for that tip. I rechecked and my earlier hashmap creation was faulty:         HashMap<String, Object> data = (HashMap<String, Object>) new HashMap<String, Object>().put("somekey", "value");  Switched to good ol HashMap data = new HashMap(); data.put("key", "value"); and this works!!

Comment: and waitForOutstandingWrites() was not required. It works even without that! obviously because the object was null!

Comment: you need this `waitForOutstandingWrites()` anyway, or you'll get errors/corrupted file half the time. I always get similar issues at unexpected moment if forgot this call :)